# Como aplicar un testing a un pipe de formateDate

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

Tengo creado un pipe para comprobar el formato de la fecha según un parámetro numérico (del 1 al 4) y necesito testear que dada una fecha y el argumento 1 se devuelve el formato esperado.

Éste es el pipe:

```
  transform(value: Date, ...args: number[]): unknown {
    let dd: number;
    let mm: number;
    let yyyy: number;
    let ddFormat: string;
    let mmFormat: string;
    let newFormat: string = '';

    let dateTransform = new Date(value);
    let type: number = args[0];

    dd = dateTransform.getDate();
    mm = dateTransform.getMonth() + 1;
    yyyy = dateTransform.getFullYear();

    ddFormat = this.needZero(dd);
    mmFormat = this.needZero(mm);

    if (type === 1) {
      newFormat = ddFormat + mmFormat + yyyy;
    }
    if (type === 2) {
      newFormat = ddFormat + ' / ' + mmFormat + ' / ' + yyyy;
    }
    if (type === 3) {
      newFormat = ddFormat + '/' + mmFormat + '/' + yyyy;
    }
    if (type === 4) {
      newFormat = yyyy + '-' + mmFormat + '-' + ddFormat;
    }

    return newFormat;
  }

  private needZero(checkNumber: number): string {
    return checkNumber < 10 ? '0' + checkNumber : String(checkNumber);
  }
}
```

Y este es el testing que estoy intentando:

```
describe('FormateDatePipe', () => {
  let pipe: FormatDatePipe;

  beforeEach(() => {
    pipe = new FormatDatePipe();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('type 1', () => {
    expect().toBe();
  })
});
```

Pero no sé como indicarle la fecha de entrada y que el valor esperado es el 1.

Gracias.

Comment: Llama a la función `transform`: `expect(pipe.transform(...argumentos))`

Answer (score 0):

Vale, lo he conseguido creando una variable y llamando a la función con sus parámetros.

```
  it('type 1', () => {
    let date = new Date(2022, 4, 10);
    expect(pipe.transform(date, 1)).toBe('10052022');
  });
```